# Multiple users posting to one database endpoint?

Tags: database, web, server, stripe-payments, web-deployment

I'm new to web development and was curious about something. When posting to an endpoint to then receive a value from a server-side function, is it problematic if multiple users are writing to the same endpoint? Can this corrupt the value returned?

For instance, I'm using Stripe in a project and you're supposed to post to an endpoint to generate a user-specific ephemeral key. There's a 1-2 second delay in the response at times, so would there be a problem if two users posted to the same endpoint within a few milliseconds?

Answer (score 2):

Capable web server software is designed with concurrency in mind, meaning a server can handle multiple user requests at the same time.

If you're curious about the specific techniques of how this is done, or web server architecture in general, this article is pretty interesting and offers some sample applications

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/three-ways-web-server-concurrency